# Making json keys lowercase Snowflake

Tags: json, object, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case-sensitive, lowercase

I have a table that looks like

| ID | DATE | FIRST_NAME | H&P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2023-02-01 | JESSICA | 40 |
| 99 | 2023-02-03 | MINA | 98 |
| 12 | 2023-01-14 | JACK | 12 |

I've created another table containing these columns as columns
by doing

```
SELECT ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) as details
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

| ID | DETAILS |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | {"DATE":"2023-02-01", "FIRST_NAME":"JESSICA", "H&P":"40"} |
| 99 | {"DATE":"2023-02-03", "FIRST_NAME":"MINA", "H&P":"98"} |
| 12 | {"DATE":"2023-01-14", "FIRST_NAME":"JACK", "H&P":"12"} |

Is there a way to modify the DETAILS column when using OBJECT_CONSTRUCT() so that the KEYS of the json are lowercase but the VALUES stay the same as they appear, so I could get something like

| ID | DETAILS |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | {"date":"2023-02-01", "first_name":"JESSICA", "h&p":"40"} |
| 99 | {"date":"2023-02-03", "first_name":"MINA", "h&p":"98"} |
| 12 | {"date":"2023-01-14", "first_name":"JACK", "h&p":"12"} |

thanks! (I would like to do this without listing out the columns as my actual table has about 400 columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys could be listed explicitly as lower cased:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_TABLE(ID INT, DATE DATE, FIRST_NAME TEXT, "H&P" INT)
AS
SELECT 12,  '2023-02-01', 'JESSICA', 40 UNION
SELECT 99,  '2023-02-03', 'MINA', 98 UNION
SELECT 12,  '2023-01-14', 'JACK', 12;

SELECT ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('date', DATE, 
                            'fist_name', FIRST_NAME,
                            'h&p', "H&P") AS details
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Output:

| ID | DETAILS |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | { "date": "2023-02-01", "fist_name": "JESSICA", "h&p": 40 } |
| 99 | { "date": "2023-02-03", "fist_name": "MINA", "h&p": 98 } |
| 12 | { "date": "2023-01-14", "fist_name": "JACK", "h&p": 12 } |

---

Using OBJECT constant syntax:

```
SELECT ID, {'date': DATE, 
            'fist_name': FIRST_NAME,
            'h&p': "H&P"} AS details
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

---

EDIT:

> Is there a way to do it without explicitly listing the columns?

Yes, one option requires flattening and building object second time which will reduce the performance:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) AS details
  FROM MY_TABLE
)
SELECT ID, OBJECT_AGG(LOWER(f.KEY), f.VALUE) AS details
FROM cte
,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => cte.details) AS f
GROUP BY ID, SEQ;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without explicitly listing the columns? The example table I provided is just a small subset of my actual table which has about 400 columns, so it would be easier to not have to write them all out as a json